# Get URL with .html ending with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to connect to a URL with JSoup.

When I use the following code

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/example.html").get();
```

The first call succeeds and the second raises an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: http://www.example.com/example.html
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:55)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:27)
  at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
  at webscraper.JsoupTest.main(JsoupTest.java:259)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: http://www.example.com/example.html
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:53)
  ... 3 more
```

I presume it has something to do with ".html" in the URL.

How can I connect to the URL with JSoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with .html, you have a blank space prefix in your second url.
Remove the blank space, it will work fine in my side.

You can use this [tool](http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html) to convert the asii to hex for lines code seperately, you will notice the second url has a redundant char '1f' on the position of 16.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Do You know how I can remove it? `url.replaceAll("\\s","")` doesn't help here.

Comment: It is quite strange, it is not an ordinary blank space `20`, it is `1f`.  Perhaps you can replace `http://`(with the strange code) with the correct `http://`.

Comment: Good tip. I did it this way: `url = "http" + url.substring(url.indexOf(":"));`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because you should encode the dashes in the URL. Try this:

```
String url = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/example.html", "UTF-8");
Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Dashes are valid characters in a URL, so there's no need to encode.